# SQLAlchemy: eager loading of more than one relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to query this structure:

```
A -> B
B -> C
B -> D
```

what's the syntax to do this with the Load interface, the documentation is not very clear on this (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload). All I see is how to do:

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
```

Given the query:

```
query(A).options(joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.c))
```

How do I go backward in the chain to specify the second relationship on B (B.d)?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly. I believe you could use a `backref` if you have it. Otherwise, you might want to define that in your `relationship` declaration.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just add another `.options(...)` with a new relationship path:

```
q = (
    session
    .query(A)
    .options(joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.c))
    .options(joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.d))
)
```

Comment: can't you also pass multiple options as positional arguments like this: `.options(joinedload(...).joinedload(...), joinedload(...).joinedload(...))` ?

Comment: @Bob It seems like `query(A).options(joinedload(B).joinedload(C))` means "C join to B, then the result join to A" rather than "join B to A and C to A".

Comment: would it also be possible to get only the count of B.d instead of the actual elements?

Comment: @Levi, yes you can, but this is not part of this question. Please search documentation or SO for `hybrid_column` or `column_property`, which are better suited for these cases.