# Sql alchemy Avoid second level joins on Parent when querying Child with a parent relationship

Tags: python, postgresql, join, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy. I have the following models
When i query for a parent with joinedloading i get the children and the dogs. This is accurate.

```
Parent
    Children
    Dogs
```

When i query for a child I and i ask to join the parent, I do not want the parent element to get dogs as well. But this seems to be what happens.None

```
Child:
    Parent:
        Dogs (i do not want this to be joined...its an unnecessary query. I just want the top level parent)
```

I want to make my query efficient so i do not want unnecessary joins.
IS there a flag i am missing in my model that will do this. The main reason why i want this is because i assume i will save some query time.

```
class Parent():
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'test'}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    children = relationship(Child, lazy='joined', passive_deletes='all')
    dogs = relationship(Dogs, lazy='joined', passive_deletes='all')


class Child():
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'test'}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('test.parent.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)

    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')
```

This is how i do my queries

```
session.query(Child).options(joinedload(Child.parent)).all()
```

Comment: Could you post complete example? There is `Dogs` class missing. Child class should be before `Parent`. How do you import `Column` and `Integer` classes? It would be great to copy your code and run it. Then fix/improve it. Not struggle to run it in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Parent` is configured to joined load its relationships that's what it does. You'll have to explicitly disable those that you don't want in this case, using [method chaining](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#controlling-loading-via-options):

```
session.query(Child).\
    options(joinedload(Child.parent).
            lazyload(Parent.dogs)).\
    all()
```

You could also use [`noload()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.noload) or [`raiseload()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.raiseload).

Comment: what if the parent has not just dogs but cats and bats as well. how do i chain all that in a no load?

Comment: You'll find the answer to that here: [SQLAlchemy: eager loading of more than one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980987/sqlalchemy-eager-loading-of-more-than-one-relationship)

Comment: Also, if that is the case, then perhaps the model could use some refactoring, and the different types of animals be combined (for example as "pets" or such).

Comment: I ended up using `.options(joinedload(Child.parent).noload('*'))`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to achieve this now, you can specify sub-relationship load options as of version 1.3.6:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#specifying-sub-options-with-load-options

```
Child.query.options(
    defaultload(Child.parent).options(
        noload(Parent.dogs)
    )
).all()
```